# 2 SQL Agent Jobs - same functions, same tables, one works, one fails

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL Agent Jobs.
One fires weekly, one is supposed to fire monthly.

The both contain a series of select statements for the same database and tables. I then email the results out. Both jobs also contact a series of insert/update statements to update the same 2 tables.

The queries for both jobs work when run directly from management studio. The email is sent, and the tables are updated.

The problem is when I run the monthly query as a job, the weekly job works as expected. I noticed yesterday, my monthly job didn't send the email it was supposed to. Upon further investigation, it did run the update statements, but the email itself failed.

The error in the log states

> "Executed as user :dbo. The EXECUTE permission was denied on the
>   object 'sp_se

Upon investigation, I do see this as being a relatively common error, and I see the fixes people are doing. That being said, I am curious why these two jobs would have different results given its the same database,  same tables, having similar queries, and looking in the job they both are being run as the same user.

Any suggestions on what to look for would be welcome.

Comment: Why you have two agent jobs if they do same work,I believe they must be different/configured different.Try scripting out the job which is not failing and try use that script

Comment: You likely have different users set in job step properties.

Comment: You are correct... Thank you!.. On the advanced tab of the step, it had DBO in it, I removed it and the job ran.

Answer (score 0):

On the advanced tab of the step, it had DBO in it, I removed it and the job ran